# How to call render on a view from inside an action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get the rendered response from the action BEFORE it returns, so something like:

```
def test

  my_html = # RENDER VIEW HERE AND ASSIGN TO VARIABLE


  render :text => my_html

end
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use render_to_string

```
def test
  my_html = render_to_string(:action => :show)

  render :text => my_html
end
```

render_to_string accepts all options that render does.

Comment: when is render called? is that behind the scenes?

Comment: can't I just call render_to_string and have it figure out the view page? or is that pushing it? hehe

Comment: Hmm. Yea, you probably can call render_to_string without any argument. I never tried it cause I have never found any situation yet where I might want to do that.